# Display:inline-block and display:flex at the same time

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there a way for a `<div>` tag to hold the properties `display: inline-block;` and `display: flex;`at the same time ?

I would like to have the rule `display: inline-block;` for the position of the division itself and the rule `display: flex;` to organize the childs of this tag.

In the following hierarchy, I would like to append the two rules for the divisions with the class "child", but I could not find a way to achieve it :

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
     <subchild1>
     <subchild2>
     ...
  </div>
  <div class="child">
     <subchild1>
     <subchild2>
     ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.child {
   display: inline-block;
   display: flex;
}
</style>
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: What about `display:flex` on the parent.

Comment: I don't think it would do the thing, because the children are divided in several rows and columns.

Comment: maybe display: inline-flex is what you're looking for?

Comment: Like already written, `display: inline-flex` is the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `display: inline-flex` instead.

Like so:

```
<style>
.child {
   display: inline-flex;
}
</style>
```

It makes the flex container display inline, but preserves the flex layout of it's children.

Comment: Does `inline-flex` make the contained `inline` or `inline-block` (as the question asks)?